# Sandbox Email ( Workflow, Process Builder, Apex ) no longer send email if user email ends in .invalid

Tags: email, workflow, process-builder, apex-email-service, email-alert

In our sandboxes Developer orgs, We have recently noticed as of May 30 2019 that emails ( workflow, process builder, apex ) have stop being sent when the invoking user's email ends in '.invalid'.  Understand Salesforce changes the users email to prevent sending emails in Sandboxes on accident but in the past logging in as that user and performing workflow / application actions still sent email alerts.

We have a case open with Salesforce.. I am curious if anyone else is seeing this?

Have documented emails that were sent via workflow email alerts prior to May 31st so this is not past behavior.

note the recent post here where this first mentioned: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000lXhVQAU

Took us a bit to confirm this so hopeful this helps the next person..

Thanks!

Comment: I presume Email Deliverability is set to `All` ?

Comment: yes! :) we successfully received emails up until the 28th..

Comment: also once we change the email from .invalid to a valid email the email alerts again begin to send..  Took us a bit of time to figure out that this was the source issue..  You have to validate the email through an emailed url click and cannot use the change password checkbox to avoid validation.

Comment: You should turn this into a question and then self-answer.  This way Community sees there is an accepted answer.

Comment: cropredy - how do i do that?  Sorry I thought this was a question..

Comment: I meant, provide an answer by answering your own question.

Comment: understood.. I'm still waiting from official response from SF Support.  Support did confirm today that this is in fact broken / not working as expected so indeed something is wrong.

Comment: If it turns into a known issue, then that is what should go in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has become an official bug:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SHorQAG

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the accepted answer, this is not a bug, this is working as designed, as of Summer '19: [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000333417&type=1) states:

> Please note as of Summer Release '19, Users must have a verified email
> address and .invalid removed from the email address in order to send
> email alerts via Workflow, Process, Flows or Triggers.