# Unable to send emails from sandbox

Tags: email

I am suddenly unable to send emails from sandbox.  This includes all emails from process flows (i.e. email alerts), email template previews, case emails, and even deliverability testing.  I checked deliverability and it is correctly set to "All Emails":
[image]

I've also verified that the emails are not going into the spam folder or being caught by my company's corporate spam blocker.  After scouring the internet, all I can find is to set deliverability to "All Email" which I've done.  Is there anything else that would prevent emails from going out?

Comment: did you look in the email log?  errors can be found there

Comment: I did.  The results were "R" (received) and "D" (delivered), but I've not received any emails.

Comment: And email addresses don't include 'invalid.com' ?

Comment: That was it.  The from address still had ".invalid".  I removed that and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(based on comment thread)

SFDC sandboxes will not send emails if the **from** or **to** recipient includes `.invalid`. By default, [sandbox users will have the email appended by `.invalid`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333417&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

see also related [Sandbox Email ( Workflow, Process Builder, Apex ) no longer send email if user email ends in .invalid](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265724/sandbox-email-workflow-process-builder-apex-no-longer-send-email-if-user-e)

Comment: I had removed ".invalid" but refreshed the sandbox a couple months ago and forgot to reset the email.  Working great now.  Thanks.

Comment: @cropredy even trying to send to my personal inbox ain't working any other suggestesions?

Comment: @compski - you should post a new question and link to this one, explaining your setup in detail and what you are experiencing. Be explicit and show all the paths you have taken to avoid it being closed as a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid spending minutes to manually remove the **.invalid** from all the email adresses, by doing it in seconds using sfdx-hardis command [sfdx hardis:org:user:activateinvalid](https://hardisgroupcom.github.io/sfdx-hardis/hardis/org/user/activateinvalid/)

```
sfdx plugins:install sfdx-hardis
sfdx hardis:org:user:activateinvalid
```

[image]

More info & demo in [this article](https://nicolas.vuillamy.fr/reactivate-all-the-sandbox-users-with-invalid-emails-in-3-clicks-2265af4e3a3d)

*Disclaimer: my company authors this plugin*

Answer (score -1):

I had to remove the ".invalid" from the default automation user's email address and that solved my issue.