# Unable to trigger email alerts on sandbox

Tags: email, email-alert, approval-process, spring22

Salesforce release version = 54.0 (Spring 22)

I had a similar question to [Unable to send emails from sandbox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/269444/38191) but this question was more generic.

My workflow involved automatically triggering the submit for approval sending email alert for approval request on the Opportunity level. Then sending back 2 more email alerts when Approving/Rejecting the Opportunity.

**Happy flow :**
When I test the end-to-end workflow with my own Admin username, I am able to get all 3 email alerts.

**Problem :**
When I test as a test user, I only can get the email alert for submitting the approval but not when approving or rejecting the Opportunity.

Checking [Unable to send emails from sandbox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/269444/38191) I also enabled Deliverability = All Email. So what is happening here? And downloading email logs, I couldn't make sense of any of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting 2 days on this issue, I submitted a case with Salesforce Support and debugged it with the Support, affected user and myself.

What we noticed was NO emails was being sent for when we used the test user not coming to both our company or personal email inboxes.

It was found that the user that is triggering the Email Alert has the email suffixed with the '.invalid' which won't trigger any email and won't appear in the Email logs.

So when testing Email alerts on sandbox, REMEMBER to use a test user with a **valid email format** (without the .invalid that is automatically added when refreshing sandboxes)